# android socket exception permission denied

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to follow this code example here: http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/04/30/logging-accelerometer-from-android-to-pc/

I am getting a socket error: Permission denied exception though.

Here is my Manifests file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.accelerometerlogger"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Relevant part of the tutorial:

```
package noe.rart;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Socket_test2Activity extends Activity {

    public int PORT = 15000;
    private Button connectPhones;
    private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.0.5";
    private boolean connected = false;
    TextView text;
    EditText port;
    EditText ipAdr;
    private float x,y,z;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    boolean acc_disp = false;
    boolean isStreaming = false;
    PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        connectPhones = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
        port=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        ipAdr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipadr);
        text.setText("Press send to stream acceleration measurement");
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        port.setText("15000");
        ipAdr.setText(serverIpAddress);
        acc_disp =false;
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener connectListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    connectPhones.setText("Stop Streaming");
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
            else{
                connectPhones.setText("Start Streaming");
                connected=false;
                acc_disp=false;
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;
        public void run() {
            try {
                acc_disp=true;
                PORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                serverIpAddress=ipAdr.getText().toString();
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("TURBOBEAVER");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, PORT);
                connected = true;
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                while (connected) {
                    out.printf("%10.2f\n", x);
                    out.flush();
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
            finally{
                try{
                    acc_disp=false;
                    connected=false;
                    connectPhones.setText("Start Streaming");
                    //out.close();
                    socket.close();
                }catch(Exception a){
                }
            }
        }
    };

   private void init_perif(){
        // smthing      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelerationListener, sensor,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerationListener);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private SensorEventListener accelerationListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
            refreshDisplay();
        }
    };

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        if(acc_disp == true){
            String output = String.format("X:%3.2f m/s^2  |  Y:%3.2f m/s^2  |   Z:%3.2f m/s^2", x, y, z);
            text.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

and logcat:

```
11-10 01:44:07.125  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
11-10 01:44:07.125  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger E/Zygote﹕ v2
11-10 01:44:07.125  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10353
11-10 01:44:07.125  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
11-10 01:44:07.145  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G900V_5.0 ver=27
11-10 01:44:07.145  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900V_5.0_0027
11-10 01:44:07.145  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-10 01:44:07.145  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-10 01:44:07.175  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
11-10 01:44:07.175  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
11-10 01:44:07.215  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.example.accelerometerlogger-2/base.apk
11-10 01:44:07.395  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-10 01:44:07.395  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-10 01:44:07.415  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 0, MPU6500 Acceleration Sensor, 0, 0,
11-10 01:44:07.445  31884-31921/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
11-10 01:44:07.565  31884-31921/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 03/03/15 Tue
    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1_20150108_025_1077123_1158499
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
11-10 01:44:07.565  31884-31921/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-10 01:44:07.605  31884-31921/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xb3a22088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8
11-10 01:44:07.615  31884-31921/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-10 01:44:07.755  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d099f83 time:608961596
11-10 01:44:18.875  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-10 01:44:19.055  31884-31884/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/System.out﹕ Starting Stream
11-10 01:44:19.065  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger I/System.out﹕ Starting client thread
11-10 01:44:19.075  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /98.157.211.152 (port 6881): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at com.example.accelerometerlogger.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:92)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
11-10 01:44:19.085  31884-32125/com.example.accelerometerlogger W/System.err﹕ ... 6 more
```

Comment: Just giving the tutorial your following is not enough we don't have time to go through the whole tutorial and find where you MAY OR MAY NOT be having the problem, you need to us explain to exactly where you are stuck and what you have tried, and when it comes to exceptions you should ALWAYS attach the logcat for that particular exception

Comment: We need the error stack.

Comment: It looks like now, I'm getting a connection refused error. In the past I was getting a permission denied error.

Comment: It is working now. Apparently it wasn't enough to close and re-open Android Studio. I had to also re-open the project.

Comment: I don't see a "permission denied" error. Also, how would you see that error when it happens inside a `try {...} catch(Exception e) {}` block, which ignores errors?

Answer (score 3):

After adding permissions, I apparently also needed to both close/open Android studio and re-open the project, or just re-open the project.

Comment: Android Studio is like that and I just love it [X|] ... sometimes it also helps to sync the project ("tools->android->sync project").